# Faster indexing in Elastic Search through rake task in rails

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I have more over 1.5 million records in my MySQL database. If I run the rake task to index data into AWS ElasticSearch, it is taking more than 3 days to complete indexing. Is there any alternative way to do faster indexing?

Comment: Use filebeat + logstash which is built for cases like this

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use Bulk API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

You can also disable index refreshing and re-enable it after you index whole dataset.

Comment: Thanks! @Michał Szajbe, I'll look into this. there is another option is to run multiple threads Or jobs for faster indexing.https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html